# Silencing output from tcpdump when using popen

Tags: c, popen, stderr, tcpdump, silent

I am writing a program in C to analyze packets that are captured by tcpdump. In my program I use `popen` to open a pipe to a tcpdump process which captures the packets and dumps the raw data to stdout as shown below.

```
FILE *tcpdump = popen("tcpdump -s0 -w -", "r");
```

However, warnings and error messages from tcpdump go straight to stderr, which is displayed in the console. I would like to somehow hide these, so only the output from my program is shown.

One way i tried was to append `2>&1` to the tcpdump command, but then my program would have to differentiate between tcpdump warnings/errors and the raw packet data.

Is there an easy way to silence the stderr output from tcpdump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

redirect stderr to /dev/null:

```
FILE *tcpdump = popen("tcpdump -s0 -w - 2>/dev/null", "r");
```

2>&1 means to redirect stderr to stdout, 2>file means to redirect stderr to file (and redirecting to /dev/null essentially ignores the output)

Look for the redirection explanation in `man bash`